# Each row of the matrix in a table using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, matrix

I have a matrix of json objects, I get it from the server and in the client side, I want to build a table with each row of the matrix.
I don't know how to do that with angular directive ng-repeat 
thank u for your help

this is app.js

```
 $scope.inspectionEnCoursDinspection=[];
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/projet/getInspectionEnCoursDinspection").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

     $scope.inspectionEnCoursDinspection1=data;
})
```

and this is my html page

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr ng-repeat="insp in inspectionEnCoursDinspection1 | orderBy: 'tests.length':'reverse' ">
<td>Mat{{insp.vehicule.matricule}}</td>
<td><div ng-repeat="aa in insp.tests">
Test<ul><li ng-repeat="defaut in aa.defauts">{{defaut.nomDefaut}}</li></ul>
</div>
</td>
</table
```

and this is one json object from the matrix

```
[{"idInspection":15,"debutInspection":null,"finInspection":null,"valide":false,"dateInspection":1462750361452,"produit":{"idProduit":1,"nomProduit":"Réinspection"},"ligne":{"idLigne":5,"description":"DES LIGNE 1","bancs":[{"idBanc":12,"description":"BANC1","ordre":1,"bancType":{"idBancType":6,"defauts":[{"idDefaut":7,"nomDefaut":"DEFAUT1"}],"description":"TYBE BANC 1"}},{"idBanc":13,"description":"BANC2","ordre":2,"bancType":{"idBancType":9,"defauts":[{"idDefaut":10,"nomDefaut":"DEFAUT4"},{"idDefaut":11,"nomDefaut":"DEFAUT5"}],"description":"TYBE BANC 2"}}],"numligne":1},"inspecteur":null,"tests":[{"idTest":16,"dureeTest":null,"testValide":false,"defauts":[{"idDefaut":7,"nomDefaut":"DEFAUT1"}]}],"termine":false,"vehicule":{"idVehicule":14,"matricule":11,"couleur":"3","carburant":"option1","modelVehicule":{"idModel":8,"marque":"MARQUE1","model":"MODEL1"}}}]
```

Comment: Please post your json data sample

Comment: could it be a typo in your ngRepeat? you wrote `ng-repeat="defaut in aa.defauts"`, is it **aa.defauts** correct?

Comment: I added it by editing my question @Ali.MD

Comment: @Ced look at my json object

Answer (score 0):

So what your code does is create a table row for every **insp** object in the **inspectionEnCoursDinspection1** array.

Within that row it then makes a cell for **insp.vehicule.matricule**

It then makes another cell and fills it with a number of lists from **insp.tests**
Each of those lists contains a number of dot points for each item in **aa**.

So a few things here. Firstly your `<tr>` tag is never closed. ie you need a `</tr>` tab before `</table>`

Next I *think* you want multiple cells for each list. In which case you should have;

```
<td ng-repeat="aa in insp.tests">Test
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="defaut in aa.defauts">{{defaut.nomDefaut}}</li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

This way you will repeat the  element which is what makes the cell in a table.

So your final code should look like this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="insp in inspectionEnCoursDinspection1 | orderBy: 'tests.length':'reverse' ">
        <td>Mat{{insp.vehicule.matricule}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="aa in insp.tests">Test
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="defaut in aa.defauts">{{defaut.nomDefaut}}</li>
           </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**:
another issue you might be having is that in your first ng-repeat you have:

> | orderBy: 'tests.length':'reverse' "

you do not want quotes around 'reverse'. It should be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="insp in inspectionEnCoursDinspection1 | orderBy: 'tests.length':reverse "
```

Comment: thank u @vanbujm I know that my code is creating a table row for every object in the matrix, but what I want is how to make it creating a table with each row in the matrix !!

Comment: Sorry, just to further clarify, you want multiple tables. Specifically a table for each object in inspectionEnCoursDinspection1?

Comment: No I want to specify a table for each row of the matrix inspectionEnCoursDinspection1

Comment: Okay so the array you supplied is not something I would typically consider as a matrix. What you have is an array of JSON objects, each object has many fields of varying lengths and depths.

As I am still unsure of what you want.

If you want multiple tables, then you need an ng-repeat in the `<table>` element.

If you want multiple rows, then you need the ng-repeat in the `<tr>` element.

If you want multiple cells, then you need a ng-repeat in the `<td>` element.

You seem to be accessing the objects correctly though, so I suspect it is the structuring that you are struggling.